# Query to get the sum of a condition from one table, and add it to same condition in another table

Tags: php, mysql

What I have is two tables;

`heli_acft`:

> - acft_id
> - acft_reg
> - acft_hours

`heli_flt`:

> - flt_id
> - flt_acft
> - flt_colhr

`acft_id` correlates to `flt_acft`.

I want to get the total sum of all `flt_colhr` of each `flt_acft` in the table, and then add that figure to the value of `acft_hours` per `acft_id`.

The result will then be displayed as a `<?php echo data[???] ?>` in a table.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: Join the tables and group by the `flt_acft`.

Comment: @juergend - Thanks, but I'm looking to group by `acft_id`

Comment: Also, thanks to all those who have helped with this question, but to the person who voted down - why? I'm sadly finding that of the Stack Exchange sites, this site seems very quick to just vote people down, with no reason why, especially when the person has a valid question. Please remember that vote down is for poorly asked questions, not just because you see it to be easily answered - we are not all as strong in some areas of development as others.

Comment: Maybe it was downvoted because you did not show what you tried. People don't like to have a list of requirements and see nothing you did. It feels like you are lazy and just want others to do the work for you. Also you did not show example data and expected output which made it a bit vague.

Comment: @juergend - Entirely true too, but generally from what I have seen, most people on here have gone to some effort to research or troubleshoot an issue before putting it on here. I generally have a rule that I don't post anything to any forum unless I've struggled with it for more than 7 days. This one is difficult for me as it also populates the entire PHP table, in a way that I've never done before, hence the difficulty. In future, I will mention other things I've tried to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `acft_id` is a unique idenfifier in `flt_acft` table...

Here is one approach to returning the specified resultset, adding the total of "hours" (from `heli_flt` to the "hours" from `heli_acft`:

```
 SELECT a.acft_id
      , a.acft_hours
      , IFNULL(f.flt_hours,0)
      , a.acft_hours + IFNULL(f.flt_hours,0) AS total_hours
   FROM heli_acft a
   LEFT
   JOIN ( SELECT SUM(h.flt_colhr) AS flt_hours
               , h.flt_acft
            FROM heli_flt h
           GROUP BY h.flt_acft
        ) f
     ON f.flt_acft = a.acft_id
```

The inline view calculates `f` calculates the sum of the hours from `heli_flt` for each `flt_acft`. A JOIN to `heli_acft` to get the `acft_hours`, and we simply add the values of the two columns. We use an "outer" join so we can return rows from `heli_acft` that don't have any related rows in `heli_flt`, and use an `IFNULL()` function to replace a NULL value with a zero.

Comment: Thanks, even more in-depth to what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables and calculate the sum. I use a `LEFT JOIN` to get a zero result for aircraft that have no flights.

```
SELECT acft_id, acft_hours + IFNULL(SUM(flt_colhr), 0) AS total_colhr
FROM heli_acft 
LEFT JOIN heli_flt ON acft_id = flt_acft
GROUP BY acft_id
```

Comment: Seems like this answer misses one bit of the specification, it gets the total hours from heli_flt, but the spec says: **"then add that figure to the value of acft_hours"**. Entirely possible I misunderstood the requirements. (We should note that this also assumes that `acft_id` is unique in the `heli_acft` table.)

Comment: +1. Now this looks like it will return the specified resultset. (My preference is to qualify all column references with a table alias.) This query is likely more efficient than the query in my answer, since my query uses an inline view ("derived table") which this avoids.